# Cannot get YML variables that are not set programatically

Tags: java, yaml, bukkit

So what I have done is I created a config as a resource in my jar. I successfully exported it to the right folder and everything. I am using bukkit/spigot because its for a plugin. My problem is, I cannot get variables' values if it is not set programmatically. Say I created all the config. I loaded it and everything. Say I wanted to get the variable. 
`option.option1`.

It would return null because this option was not set using the methods. I decided to test and set a variable `option.test` 
in the class. And I tried to get the value. It worked. Now I do not know why it won't load anything that isn't set in the program. I have searched te internet and found nothing at all. I don't know if any code is needed to be provided, but I am really stuck on this one.

Code:
`getConfig().getString("option.option1"); //Returns null, this option is set by hand in the config` 
`getConfig().getString("option.test"); //Gets the variable. This is set programitally.`
`Using getConfig().set("option.test", "COMPLETE");`

Comment: Can you post the code? Without the code must gues what the problem might be. Try looking into a [mcve].

Comment: @Ferrybig there you go ._. don't know why its that important.

Comment: @Ferrybig Don't worry I fixed it, it was just some file saving issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind I fixed my own problem. It was just to do with some file loading/saving issues.